# Binding time to a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, ajax

I am using a Masked Editor which is great and simple to use, but I was wondering. Is there a way to bind the time to a textbox that has a masked editor and cause the AM or PM to show up?

I know if you type an A or P AM and PM will show up, but how to you get it to appear to a bound textbox of time?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttime" runat="server" Width="90"></asp:TextBox>
                         <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID = "MaskedEditExtender1" AcceptAMPM="true"  ClearTextOnInvalid="true" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" runat="server" TargetControlID="txttime"
                         Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
                         <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID = "MEV"  ControlToValidate="txttime" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" IsValidEmpty="false"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
```

**Here is the code that binds to the textbox. All i see is the time without AM or PM**

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(FormView1.DataItem, "Date"));   
txttime.Text = String.Format("{0:t}", datetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
MaskType="Number"
```

To

```
MaskType="DateTime"
```

And include the following parameter:

```
AcceptAMPM="true"
```

So it would now be:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttime" runat="server" Width="90"></asp:TextBox>
                         <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID = "MaskedEditExtender1" AcceptAMPM="true"  ClearTextOnInvalid="true" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" runat="server" TargetControlID="txttime"
                         Mask="99:99" MaskType="DateTime" AcceptAMPM="true"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
                         <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID = "MEV"  ControlToValidate="txttime" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" IsValidEmpty="false"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Comment: I had Masktype = "Time". That works. Masktype = "Datetime" doesn't work. I also already have AMPM = "true"

Answer (score 1):

ClearMaskOnLostFocus must be set to true. That was the issue. Thanks for the help.

```
ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"
```

Here's where i found the answer

[Click here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1334426/2694140.aspx#2694140)